# Should I use SQL Reporting Services 2008 for my reporting engine?

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to use SQL Reporting Services 2008 to generate my reports, but I want to use my own UI for specifying the report type, columns, parameters and everything.  I want to be able to take these criteria, and then kick off an asynchronous request to SSRS and have the report emailed to me.  Is this possible?  I don't want to go all the way down the road of researching SQL Reporting Services 2008 only to find that it doesn't do what I need it to do.  Also, I will have a ton of DB partitions that the data will need to be pulled from.  Some reports will need to pull data from only one of these, but other ones may actually need to span different databases.  Is it possible when sending a report request to SSRS to specify what servername/database to pull the data from?  Is it possible to tell it to take the data from multiple databases and combine it?  Thanks.

Comment: You should rewrite this question and list what your specific concerns are that the Reporting Services might limit you, then people can properly meter if the Reporting Services is what you want, but if you have to flip a coin, I'd say more than likely, it is all you need.

Answer (score 3):

Like Crystal Reports, ActiveReports and other report generators, SSRS has two basic elements behind each report: the SQL query and the report layout. No matter what tool you use for the SQL -- it can be inline SQL in the report or a call to a stored procedure -- it's going to be the same query. Multiple databases are fine as long as you can specify them up front.

You can have parameterized queries, so the user is prompted to input the relevant filters (customer ID, product group, date range, whatever).

Doing the report layout is similar to other tools -- you drag and drop controls like labels onto the report, and set their formatting.

SSRS does provide a lot of options for distributing the report, including email. You can embed the report in an ASP.Net web page, leave it on the report server site for users to browse to, run it in the wee hours of the morning and cache it so every user doesn't have to wait for the lengthy query to run.

It's a great tool. I think it will be worth your effort to experiment with it. I would wait on creating the customized UI until you've exhausted the possibilities inherent in the tool.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS is not designed with this scenario in mind, for that matter I am not sure that any out of the box reporting solution is going to have an elegant solution for this. While SSRS can do what you are asking (as well as others), it is by no means quick or easy. You seem to be looking for an advanced ad-hoc solution with dynamic sourcing of the data. I would first question the requirements and determine if the business scenario really justifies such an implementation. I would weigh custom building a solution vs your learning curve with a BI reporting solution. You may find that it is easier to just build something on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I think the heterogeneous dynamic database mashup is probably going to be the most challenging part.

Depending on what your scalability requirements are, one place that has that part covered, and a report writer, is Access. (Duck! Incoming!)

Comment: You ARE brave to suggest Access, but that's not a bad idea for this situation. It's a great tool, but easy to abuse. So, if you know what you're doing, it could be just the answer. And if it doesn't satisfy the long-term needs, you end up with a great proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be creating a rod for your own back to a certain extent as RS ships with a few interfaces for report creation.

Mind you the end product is an rdl file which is nothing but xml, so you can write them by hand if you really like.

Multiple data sources are supported, but combining them on a single control/chart/etc are not, so you'll need to configure yourself a cross database capability from one of your data-sources prior to the report request if you want to do that.